# Use unrelated SQL tables in an ASP.NET Core MVC view

Tags: sql, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application related to sports. I know that within the view, the data gets imported together with the controller which sends the data. Within this controller, I know you can include related SQL tables, however I want to view a unrelated table

For your context:

- I use a SQL table
- I set up the application in the application in the first place by using this tutorial:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfEjDD8mWYg&t=1573s
- Its about a sports application. I want to show the games where a certain player/coach has been involved with. The game has an `organizationId`, this organization has a team and this team has a coach an players.

I have been looking in to it, but I can't seem to find any solution suitable for my use case, but I know it should be possible somehow. For example i looked into this topic: [Including unrelated data in a view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408431/including-unrelated-data-in-a-view-model)

I am mostly looking to give access to the full database from the specific view, or pass 2 '@model', but since this is impossible, something similar to it would be enough.

This particular response lacked a bit of explanation of implementation in other any other context. So if this is a suitable solution, please explain. When you need more information or context regarding my issue, do not hesitate to ask.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by following step 6 & 7 on this tutorial:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/display-multiple-tables-in-a-single-view-in-asp-net-mvc/

The stackoverflow topic I talked about in the question, was somewhat right. The only differnce was that I needed multiple records, where the topic only covered single records

Comment: Hi, it'd be better if you actually describe step 6 & 7, or maybe even more of the tutorial. Now you've posted a link, but if that link ever gets taken down or whatever this answer becomes useless to other people coming across it because they have no way of knowing step 6 & 7.